# GitLab disable regular username password login and only allow OmniAuth login

Tags: omniauth, gitlab

I have gitlab all set up and ready with omniauth and I was wondering if it is possible to disable default authentication with password and username entirely and to use only omniauth (in our case google login). What I'm hoping to achieve is enhanced security through enforced two factor authentication with google apps bundled together with omniauth.

Comment: If no one comes up with an answer open a feature request at: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After Gitlab version 7.7.0, you can now set up sign-up and sign-in behaviour in the **Admin area**, under the **Settings** page. Unchecking `Signin enabled` option will only let OAuth login available.

Note that `gitlab_rails['gitlab_signin_enabled']` and `gitlab_rails['gitlab_signup_enabled']` settings in `gitlab.rb` now [have no effect](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/8648).

Answer (score 3):

This functionality was added in v 6.8.

You need to change the setting in gitlab.yml to `signin_enabled: false` or add `gitlab_rails['gitlab_signin_enabled'] = false` to gitlab.rb if you are using Omnibus.